# Why am I getting extra characters when writing to a file from a string?

Tags: c, macos, unix, system-calls

My program opens a file descriptor with [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), writes a string to the file using [`write`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), then closes the file descriptor. When I check the file contents, it has additional characters after the string. Visual Studio Code shows these as "␀" (a single codepoint with the letters "NUL"); a screenshot below shows exactly how they appear in VS Code. Why are these extra characters in the file?

```
// test.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(){
    int fd = open("out.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
    strcpy(buff, "This is a test message!\n");
    write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    close(fd);
}
```

[image: This is out.txt file]

Comment: Why are you including all those header files? For the program you have written only a few of them will be needed.

Comment: You wrote BUFSIZ characters. By the way, the picture is unreadable, though it tells you the answer.

Comment: What's ```BUFSIZ```?

Comment: As for your problem, what is the difference between `sizeof(buff)` and `strlen(buff)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i written all of them bcause i will use dirent and sockets and everything later.

Comment: 1024 depends on machine as well

Comment: I suspect the `NUL` characters have something to do with `bzero()` call.

Comment: We are not here to scrutinize your "future code". Better post a minimal example. On the opposite, the code is incomplete and someone willing to compile it would be in trouble.

Comment: @YvesDaoust including header file wont cause any  issue so that wont matter and for compiling part its compiling just fine if u dont belive in can give u screen rec

Comment: @mouviciel thanks it worked the issue was with that bzero thing

Comment: Well you write the whole buffer, which contains a lot of zero bytes. So that's what you see.

Comment: @ewong "What's BUFSIZ" --> `BUFSIZ` is defined in `<stdio.h>`: "... an integer constant expression that is the size of the buffer used by the `setbuf` function", "... value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256.".

Comment: If you don't call `bzero` (or the preferred `memset`), then the majority of the buffer will have *indeterminate* contents. You should look at it as random, or even garbage. And that doesn't help with the problem of writing all that data to the file, instead of zeroes you write "garbage" data to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));` writes out at least 256 bytes as that is the size of `char buff[BUFSIZ];` and  `BUFSIZ` (from `<stdio.h>`) is at least 256.

In addition to `"This is a test message!\n"`, hundreds of *null characters* are also written.  For OP, they show up as "some additional things". [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568905/getting-invalid-characters-while-writing-to-file-using-system-c/71569668#comment126491099_71568905)

If only `"This is a test message!\n"` is desired, do not write hundreds of bytes, but only the length of the *string*.  [@SwirlyManager75](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71569219/2410359)

```
// write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. I have a small question in this case we used char[] so strlen worked but how to use this if i write a struct object in a file.

Comment: @jugalShah  Do you want to write the _struct object_ as text or as binary data?  With `char buff[BUFSIZ];`, you did not want the binary data of the entire object, just the string portion of it.

Comment: i want to write whole object and then read by another program. i used this to start with only but i think for object strlen wont work and still bufsiz will create those unknown characters issue

Comment: @jugalShah Using `strlen()` to determine length to send does not send the whole object.  `strlen()` only sends the first part of the characters array that forms the _string_.  Use `sizeof()` to determine length to send the whole object.  `"This is a test message!\n"` is not the whole object.  `"This is a test message!\n\0\0\0...\0\0\0"` is the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and change your code as follows.

```
//bzero call is useless
write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
```

the problem is that you have to write the exact number of bytes into the file, so you must use the strlen function, which counts the characters on a string till the first \0, which in this case is automatically placed after the \n by the compiler (see [this](https://icarus.cs.weber.edu/%7Edab/cs1410/textbook/8.Strings/c_string.html#:%7E:text=The%20compiler%20automatically%20adds%20the,is%20also%20copied%20to%20s2%20.)).

Comment: BTW The call to `memset` is useless.

Comment: And why the `\0` at the end of the string?

Comment: Yes in this case the explicit \0 is not mandatory to form a string, but since the array was just declared (so there is memory garbage in it) and given the fact that OP is using strcpy and then writing sizeof(buff) bytes  the write will not stop to the first \0 (because there is none), so with memset you just fill the array with \0s and then copy the string into buff

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oooh now i see, so with literal strings the null terminator is automatically added by the compiler...didn't know that, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct; string literals are implicitly NUL-terminated. What you create here is a *doubly* NUL-terminated string. Also, as has been pointed out, the `memset` is pointless; there's no need to zero-fill the buffer before copying in a NUL-terminated string. Please consider updating your answer to make it more complete (perhaps including some of what you've learned here in the comments, as others may have the same confusion).